# How to find a pattern background?

Tags: css, design-patterns, background-image, image

I am looking for a image pattern similar to the one Path.com uses:

```
     https://www.path.com/images/about/bg.gif
```

I want a similar image pattern so i can use it as a background for my website.  It will be helpful if i can find a way to create it too.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @Pekka, how can i find a similar pattern so i can use it as a background for my website.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. You mean the texture. Google "texture archive", you'll find a number of good archives. If you don't find what you're looking for, ask on `graphicdesign.stackexchange.com` (it's not really programming related - closing as off-topic)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know we had a graphic design section.  Thanks.

Comment: Design patterns don't refer to design as in image textures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://www.backgroundlabs.com/ website

I'm sure you've tried this but also try searching for these words on google "background textures". It does bring up some really nice backgrounds similar to what you're looking for.

It lets you even browse by color. Hope this helps.